# Understanding WHY gradle complains about colliding versions

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have been trying to bring back an old app of mine, that I wrote a while back using eclipse. I imported to android-studio and I it complains about colliding versions:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 28.0.0-alpha1, 27.1.0. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0-alpha1 and
>   com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0

At first, I solved it as suggested by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification) question, by including the colliding packages specifically in the gradle file with the newer version. So my gradle file ended up like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tomklino.imhere"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }


    dependencies {
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
        implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
        implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
        implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0"
        implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

This removed the red line from under the `appcompat` line, but then, after debugging something else, I got the message above again, but this time with the version 28.0.0-alpha1. Now I can't include the new version, because if I try it says it is incompatible with the sdk version of 27.

I'm trying to understand why it asks for that version in the first place if I havn't included that sdk version anywhere. Nothing in the dependency tree asks for the 28.0.0-alpha1 version specifically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but then, after debugging something else, I got the message above again, but this time with the version 28.0.0-alpha1

Replace:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
```

with:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
```

and resolve to stop using `+` for the entire version of an artifact.

> I'm trying to understand why it asks for that version in the first place if I havn't included that sdk version anywhere.

You used `+` for the version of `appcompat-v7`. This says that you want the latest that Gradle can find. And, last week, Google released `28.0.0-alpha1`, in tandem with the release of the Android P Developer Preview 1.

Comment: I have no dependencies with + but i still have the problem

Comment: @porfirion: You may want to ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide a [mcve] showing your error and the files triggering the error (e.g., `app/build.gradle`).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but no of dependencies had '+' in version number.
Problem was in xwalk (Crosswalk WebView) library.
I've solved it by adding 'transitive':

```
compile ('org.xwalk:xwalk_core_library:23.53.589.4') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

Comment: I assume that this library has support-v4 library inside and that is why conflict occure